# MVC architecture like Laravel

Tags: php, oop, routes, laravel

Recently I started learning Laravel and is really good PHP framework. Currently I'm trying to make my own MVC similar how Laravel works.

**My logic**

We set the routes, then we check if the current URL exist and from there we will set the controller and the method from `'uses'`, if not we will set the controller to `ERROR`.
The problem is that I can't access the $routes variable.

If i try `static::$routes = ..` the php shows an error, but Lavarel is working ok even though my PHP version is **5.2** . I don't understand how the whole thing works. Also if you have any suggestions how to structure the architecture :)

**index.php**

```
include 'router.php';
include 'route.php';


Route::get('about',array('uses'=> 'about@index'));
Route::get('about2',array('uses'=> 'about@index'));
```

**router.php**

```
class Router {

    public static $routes = array(
        'GET'    => array(),
        'POST'   => array(),
        'PUT'    => array(),
        'DELETE' => array(),
        'PATCH'  => array(),
        'HEAD'   => array(),
    );

    public $valid = false;

    public static $methods = array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD');


    public static function register($method, $route, $action)
    {       

        if (ctype_digit($route)) $route = "({$route})";

        if (is_string($route)) $route = explode(', ', $route);

        foreach ((array) $route as $uri){
            if (is_array($action)){
                $routes[$method][$uri] = $action;
            }
        }

        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $request = trim($request, '/');

        $exist = array_key_exists($request, $routes[$method]);

        if($exist){
            $valid = true;
        } 

        echo $valid;

        // print_r($routes);
    }

}
```

**route.php**

```
class Route {


    public static function get($route, $action)
    {
        Router::register('GET', $route, $action);
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you are setting up your own framework I suggest dropping all the `static`s everywhere. They only make it realy really hard to unit test your code. Instead look into [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: I'm removing the **`mvc`** tag. The question is completely unrelated to it.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to copy and paste a work, please understand the whole process first before assuming everything is plain static, do read up on:

- [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)
- [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)
- [Multiton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are only using local variables. When dealing with classes the objects variables are accessed via `$this->` and static variables - with `self::` or `static::`.

> **<sub>http://codepad.org/F7UWmOSb</sub>**

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $bar = 'lorem';
    protected $buz = 'ipsum';

    public function test()
    {
        var_dump( $this->buz );
        var_dump( self::$bar );
    }

}


$instance = new Foo;
$instance->test();
```

Also, as *@PeeHaa* mentioned: stop using static variables. It is not OOP. Static structures are just global variables/functions wrapped in a namespace, which just happens to look like `class` definition.

And learn about dependency injection, these lectures might help :

- [Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc)
- [Global State and Singletons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)
- [Don't Look For Things!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)
- [Unit Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w)

Comment: The laravel framework is writen with static method i'm just copying there code. Because i dont to use the whole framework just to make my own simple/smaller version

Comment: Well i just want to have MVC architecture and I like the way in lavarel works